# Visual Studio 2013 - Database problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I have created a SQL Server database on a server.

There is no problem connecting to it with SQL Server Management Studio. I then went to add two tables to it.

After that I connected to the database in VS 2013, again it comes up and shows the tables.

The problem is that when I double click a table (in VS 2013 Ultimate) it says

> Login failed for user 'User'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using integrated security or specifying a username and password?

Comment: I'm specifying username/password that I chose myself.

Comment: Which authentification mode did you pick when you created the database. Also are you logged in as user when you execute VS?

Comment: I could not choose authenfication mode

Answer (score 0):

To login using username password, then you should have appropriate roles assigned for the login like DBA to modify the database. Check whether that you have assigned the required roles to your login.

Comment: I have three options when creating users.
Read
Write
DDL-adminstrator
They are all active for all users.